# How much clay will I need?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I read off of UESP that a Clay deposit in Skyrim (as added by Hearthfire) will yield 4000 units of Clay per month before depleting.

That being said, I'm going to try and mine literally all the clay I'll need before building my house(s), so that I won't ever have to deal with it again. Assuming that I attempt to max out all three houses, how much clay will I need overall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compared to some other resources (like quarried stone or wood) not all that much.

[The Elder Scrolls Wiki article on Homesteads](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Homestead) has handy tables for determining the total costs of every stage of building (to view tables that include furnishings, you may have to delve slightly deeper and click on the links to individual build items). Each Homestead has the same building stages: Small house > Main hall > Add 3 Wings. Ultimately, unless you build each house with the exact same wings, costs will vary between them.

However, since you are interested in knowing the maximum amount of clay you will ultimately need to mine, here are the clay totals including furnishings (I've included the clay costs of the remaining 6 wings for comparison):

- Small House: **4**
- Main Hall: **24**
- *North wing*, Trophy Room: **13**

  - Storage Room: 3
  - Alchemy Laboratory: 9
- *East wing*, Library: **9**

  - Armory: 3
  - Kitchen: 5
- *West wing*, Greenhouse: **21**

  - Bedrooms: 3
  - Enchanter's Tower: 9
- Exterior: **6**

For a maximum total of 77 clay *per homestead*, or **231 clay** for all three.

Comment: When you think about it though, it really isn't all that much. Just start mining the clay, go watch a YouTube video, and you'll have more than enough in no time

Comment: @Ben That's effectively what I did for stone; Started mining, went to use the washroom, made some tea, let it steep, came back and dragged it all at a snail's pace to the construction chest.